# How to move node/parent node of TreePanel to another TreePanel?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

I'm not ExtJS expert. I have a problem on moving node of TreePanel to another TreePanel. I need a example that move node/if node is children then move it with parent node/ to another TreePanel. In addition I'm using ExtJS 4. I'm google it whole days but no luck :(. Please help me?

Here is the my code:

```
var models = this.getStockFromProductTree().getSelectionModel().getSelection();
var root = this.getStockToProductTree().getRootNode();
root.appendChild(models);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Drag & Drop example:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#tree-two